# Looking for a fantasy story about a young person who can hide magic

Tags: story-identification, books

I cannot remember when I read this book but a few key points keep coming back to me:

- The protagonist (cannot remember gender) lives in a secluded valley.
- The protagonist's family has a carved spoon that has been passed down through generations that appears normal until the protagonist leaves the valley.
- The protagonist learns that by touching magical objects they can make the magic become dormant, the spoon is magical but must be kept dormant by being strapped to the protagonist's skin.
- Somewhere in the story is a man with extremely long hair that can shape-shift... I think he is, somehow, linked to the carved spoon.

I know it doesn't seem much to go on but I remember snippets of this story and would love to be able to find it again